# Calculating difference with only natural numbers in R

Tags: r

I want to classify my data based on the difference in 2 years. 
 I wanted to use the diff function but it does not work with negative numbers.

I get this error

```
'lag' and 'differences' must be integers >= 1
```

```
df$new_var <- fcase(
  df$year1== df$year2, '4',
  diff(df$year1, df$year2) <= 5, '3',  
  diff(df$ipodate1, df$ipodate2) <= 10, '2',
  default = '0'
)
```

Is there a way I can calculate differences in absolute values

```
df <- data.frame(
  year1 = c('1997','2008','2004','2010','2005','2007','2008'),
  year2 = c('1997','2018','1988','1929','2023','2012','2009'))
```

So the end should look sth like this:

| year1 | year2 | new_var |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1997 | 1997 | 4 |
| 2008 | 20018 | 2 |
| 2004 | 1988 | 0 |

...

Comment: 1. `year` should be numeric type  2.  In `diff(df$year1, df$year2) <= 5`, LHS is vector, RHS is just a single `5`

Comment: check ?diff, you have to check arguments

Comment: I used ?diff but I didnt find a solution. I am not good at programming and have no idea what you mean. In my data year is numeric

Comment: your year columns are factors, so first transform them to integer. Then just use col3 = year1 - year2 or cols3 = abs(year1- year2). So you can use fcase on col3. Do it in 2 steps it will be easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I will turn `df` into the numeric type firstly. Then I prefer to use `fcase` in the `data.table` method as the following

```r
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(
  year1 = c('1997','2008','2004','2010','2005','2007','2008'),
  year2 = c('1997','2018','1988','1929','2023','2012','2009')
)

% to numeric type
df2 <- data.frame(apply(df,2, FUN=function(x) as.numeric(x)))

setDT(df2)[,newvar:=fcase(year1 == year2,4,
                          abs(year1 - year2) <= 5, 3,
                          abs(year1 - year2) <= 10, 2,
                          default = 0)]
#   year1 year2 newvar
#1:  1997  1997      4
#2:  2008  2018      2
#3:  2004  1988      0
#4:  2010  1929      0
#5:  2005  2023      0
#6:  2007  2012      3
#7:  2008  2009      3
```

Comment: Second row should be 2 ? or not?

Comment: It should be 2.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `dplyr` way using `case_when` and `abs`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(new_var = case_when(year1 == year2 ~ 4,
                             abs(year1-year2) <=5 ~3,
                             abs(year1-year2) <=10 ~2,
                             TRUE ~ 0))
```

output:

```
  year1 year2 new_var
1  1997  1997       4
2  2008  2018       2
3  2004  1988       0
4  2010  1929       0
5  2005  2023       0
6  2007  2012       3
7  2008  2009       3
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `cut` passing breaks and labels.

```
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
df$new_var <- cut(abs(df$year1 - df$year2),c(-Inf, 0, 5, 10, Inf), c(4, 3, 2, 0))
df

#  year1 year2 new_var
#1  1997  1997       4
#2  2008  2018       2
#3  2004  1988       0
#4  2010  1929       0
#5  2005  2023       0
#6  2007  2012       3
#7  2008  2009       3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `findInterval`, which is more efficient

```
df$new_var <- c(4, 3, 2, 0)[findInterval(abs(Reduce(`-`, type.convert(df, 
    as.is = TRUE))), c(-Inf, 0, 5, 10, Inf), left.open = TRUE)]
df$new_var
[1] 4 2 0 0 0 3 3
```